# Why doesn't one of my light fixtures work when I install LED bulbs?

Tags: electrical, led

I have 2 light fixtures in the bathroom. Each fixture takes 2 light bulbs. I replaced the light bulbs with LED light bulbs, but only one of the fixtures' lights works. The other one the lights do not come on. When I put the original spiral bulbs back in, it works fine. What could be the reason those lights don't work in that particular fixture?

Comment: Any dimmer, timer, or "smart" switch installed? Or just an ordinary toggle on/off?

Comment: Have you reversed the bulbs to verify that they all work?

Comment: Try putting in one LED and one incandescent.  Does the incandescent and LED suddenly both work?